# Detecting bogus values in GpsSatellite.getAzimuth() and getElevation()

Tags: android

I am the author of [SatStat](https://github.com/mvglasow/satstat/wiki), and Android app which, among others, displays the visible GPS satellites in a sky plot.

Under certain circumstances the app will display all visible satellites at an azimuth and elevation of zero (or almost zero), indicating that the Android API is returning bogus values.

**How can I filter out such values and display only the good ones?**

An example screenshot is at https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/16572/1146040/ebc2e032-1e40-11e3-8232-905c1d9c8505.png (screenshot os from an old version of the app but the bug is still the same).

The relevant code (simplified) is:

```
public class MainActivity implements GpsStatus.Listener {
    // [...]

    public void onGpsStatusChanged (int event) {
        GpsStatus status = mLocationManager.getGpsStatus(null);
        Iterable<GpsSatellite> sats = status.getSatellites();
        gpsStatusView.showSats(sats);
    }
}
```

The `showSats()` method generates logcat events whenever azimuth and elevation are both near zero.

I have run into this condition again when I had no data connection, just after GPS startup, indicating the issue is likely caused by missing or incomplete orbital data for a satellite from which the GPS has received a signal. However, another time I ran into this just sfter refreshing AGPS data (using SatStat 1.7, which checks the network connection before requesting the update), hence I should have had valid AGPS data that time.

In both cases the logcat had a lot of entries like these:

```
12-27 22:34:37.761 D/GpsStatusView( 1403): Satellite 12, snr=33.000000, azimuth=0.000000, elevation=1.000000, almanac=false, ephemeris=false, used=false
12-27 22:34:37.761 D/GpsStatusView( 1403): Satellite 15, snr=35.000000, azimuth=0.000000, elevation=1.000000, almanac=false, ephemeris=false, used=false
12-27 22:34:37.765 D/GpsStatusView( 1403): Satellite 17, snr=29.000000, azimuth=0.000000, elevation=1.000000, almanac=false, ephemeris=false, used=false
12-27 22:34:37.765 D/GpsStatusView( 1403): Satellite 26, snr=33.000000, azimuth=0.000000, elevation=1.000000, almanac=false, ephemeris=false, used=false
```

There are four satellites, all with an azimuth of zero degrees and an elevation of one degree, no almanac and no ephemeris, and not used in the fix. (In the screenshot linked above, the API reports two satellites in view and both used in the fix, which is in itself strange.)

So I can rule out drawing errors in my app – it seems the Android API is returning bogus information for azimuth and elevation. Apparently this happens when orbit data for a satellite is not available. However, I don't know if Android uses a fixed combination of azimuth/elevation in that case, and whether these values can be assumed to be consistent across devices.

Any ideas on how I can detect if the azimuth and elevation are reliable? Some error is acceptable, but I want to filter out complete bogus values. Ideas I have abandoned:

- Discarding satellites with an azimuth and elevation of precisely zero – this failed as the bogus values are near-zero, but not precisely zero (in the above case, elevation reported was 1°)
- Checking `hasAlmanac()` and `hasEphemeris()` – even sats used in a fix may (and on my device do) have both set to `false`, leaving me with an empty sky plot despite valid data
- Checking for two satellites with the exact same azimuth and elevation – while I would believe such a constellation to be a sure sign of bogus data, it will fail if there is just one satellite in view, or if just one satellite reports bogus data, or if each satellite has different bogus data.